# What is wrong with using one session key for an entire session in hybrid encryption?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I am making an Android application which involves two phones exchanging a lot of data over several minutes. I would like this communication to be encrypted and have been researching the various cryptographic options available. It seems like the most suited would be a hybrid algorithm, that uses asymmetric encryption (like RSA) to exchange a session key and a symmetric algo (like AES) to actually encrypt / decrypt the data.

From what I know of hybrid encryption, every packet sent between the two devices should use a new session key, which is embedded within the packet (encrypted with the other party's public key) to facilitate decryption at the other end.

To save CPU, I am considering using just one session key which is exchanged using RSA, and then encrypting / decrypting **all** data using this key, so that I can save on costly RSA operations. However, I understand that this is not recommended? Can someone please confirm this and tell me how I should proceed?

**EDIT:**

Thought I would add some more information here -

The communication protocol is completely custom and my own. Data is sent in unencrypted UDP packets, with a lot of metadata and an encrypted payload. So that rules out using regular SSL / TLS.

Also, for every session I generate new private and public keys, exchange the public keys and then use that to exchange a session key which is used in AES. I am using 2048-bit RSA and 256-bit AES. This, AFAIK, is more than enough and probably overkill for most communication. I will admit that my knowledge of cryptography isn't excellent, but I'm reading and learning as much as I can to make this as secure as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing 'wrong' with it, just a security tradeoff. The longer the keys, the longer the session can be. You're trying to keep the key long enough, or the session short enough, or a mixture, such that key compromise is infeasible in the time available. You also need to consider whether it's OK to leak the data for the entire session if a key gets cracked, or whether you need the extra security of a new key per message or whatever.

Comment: Given the sheer size of 2^128, the amount of data you can send with any reasonable symmetric cipher has almost nothing to do with the key length. For say counter mode, you do have to worry about the counter flipping over, but thats not the key

Comment: @imichaelmiers I didn't say anything about the 'amount of data'. It is a *space-time* tradeoff. Length of key versus time available to the attacker.

Comment: @#EJP. The attacker has all the time in the world to figure out your key and read the data you sent no matter the key length.  So what's the trade off?

Comment: The actual limit is that most blockcipher-modes become weaker once you approach 2^(b/2) blocks in length where b is the block size in bits. But for a 128 bit block cipher that's practically unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a l long live TLS/SSL session? This does pretty much exactly what you want, efficiently and doesn't require you to write tricky crypto code you will almost certainly get wrong.

In general, almost any crypto system I am aware of generates one symmetric key for the entire session and uses that for the duration. This is what TLS does and what SSH does. I believe this is what IPSEC does. There is no problem with this from a cryptographic point of view assuming you use a sane cipher like AES have sufficiently large IVs/Counters/Nonces such that they don't repeat.

The one worry about using this is that if your secret key leaks, you loose all the data in the  session.  However, if your secret key can leak, so too can your private key. At which point an attacker could decrypt previous session keys and get the data even if you followed the one key per packet mode.